# looking for a formula to add unchecked cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with a series of numbers with a check box in the cell next to them. I would like to automatically calculate these numbers when the check box is unchecked. I have used the array formula to automatically add the numbers when the check box is checked but can't figure out how to do it when they are unchecked.

I have trued true false statements but that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

First, set a link cell for each checkboxes

1. Open your worksheet which you want to count or sum the checked checkboxes, then right click one checkbox, and choose Format Control.
2. In the Format Object dialog box, click Control tab, and then click doc-checkbox-button-1 button beside the Cell link option to select a blank cell which relative to your selected checkbox as the link cell, and don’t change any other options.
3. And then click OK to close this dialog, there will be a TRUE displayed at the selected cell if the checkbox is check, and a blank cell if the checkbox is unchecked.
4. Then you need to repeat above steps to set a link cell for each checkbox of the column, and had better link the cell with the corresponding checkbox in the same row.
   Second, you can apply formulas to calculate the checkboxes
5. After finishing setting the link cell for the checkboxes, you can use the below formulas to calculate the checkboxes:

Count the checked checkbox:

=COUNTIF(D2:D15,TRUE) (D2:D15 is the range of the link cells that you have set for the checkboxes), then press Enter key to get the number of checked checkboxes.
Sum the cell values based on checked checkbox:

=SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$15=TRUE)*$C$2:$C$15), (D2:D15 is the range of the link cells that you have set for the checkboxes, and C2:C15 refers to the cells that you want to sum) and then press Enter key to add the checked checkboxes related to the values in column C.